# Is Hibernate recognizing changes by the result of the Getter?

Tags: java, hibernate

How does Hibernate recognize a change in a object? Is it inspecting the field directly or using the associated Getter-method?

Say i have a price column in the database. Under certain conditions the price shall be converted. Can i do this in the Getter-method and return the converted value without changing the value of this column if i persist this object? A change made by the Setter of this property should change the column though.

What is the default behaviour? Can it be changed? Is this a good practice or should it be avoided by using a "getConvertedPrice"-method, because the behaviour may change with a different configuration/version which yields to hard-to-find bugs?

Edit: Request Example code ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public class Item {
    /*...*/
    @Column(name="item_price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name="item_currency")
    // More enum mapping ...
    private Currency currency;

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        if(getCurrency()!=Currency.US_DOLLAR) {
            return price * CurrencyService.getCurrentRate(getCurrency());
        } else {
            return price;
        }
    }
    /*..*/
}
```

Comment: Please include some code, because I don't see how a price could be converted from a getter without changing another property of the object. Also, tell us how you map your classes: annotations? on fields or on getters? XML?

Comment: @nizet: Say you have another field which represents the currency. The price has a default currency and for every other currency you have to convert the price by a rate you fetch somewhere else. If the currency will be changed this has to be reflected by the java objects. This is a legacy database design which i can not change.

Comment: See axtavt's answer. But your design is dubious. If I set your item to be 5 (the price) euros (the currency), and I ask for the price, I expect to get 5. Not 6.392. Your getPrice() method should be named getPriceInUSDollars(). But I wouldn't make an entity dependent on a conversion service. This method should be in the service layer, IMHO.

Comment: @Nizet: I totally agree. Unfortunately there are some constraints which force me to do it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on access type of an entity. By default it's deduced from placement of mapping annotations (on fields or on properties).

You can override access type for specific field using [`@Access`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Access.html) annotation (or [`@AccessType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/AccessType.html) for old versions of Hibernate).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that the disadvantage (which still worth it) of using Hibernate. It takes control over your entities. I'll give two examples:

1. You've got to have a default constructor which is at least protected. That compromises thread safety <strike>and prevents you from making your entity immutable (which has many advantages)</strike>.
2. If your entity refers child entities as a OneToMany association, you'd naturally have some `public Collection<Child> getChildren()` method. But if you want to supply an unmodifiable collection of your children - Hibernate will fail it.

So. Try to separate any logic from your mapped object (entity) as much as you can. Treat your entity as a struct of which purpose is to communicate with the DB. Put your logic in the services layer.

**EDIT**
After reading Voo's comment: immutability is actually not something you'd usually need from mapped objects. Thread safety, though, is quite often essential.

Comment: Having a default constructor does not mean you can't make the class immutable. Sure hibernate has to set the values, but that's where reflection comes in handy..

Comment: @Voo - If I have a default constructor, I can't make my fields final - that is mutability (even if I don't actually expose the field to any change other than Hibernate's set).

Comment: But to tell the truth, immutability is not something I need from a mapped object. Thread safety, though, might be very important. I'll fix the answer a bit.

Comment: Immutability != only final fields. `BigInteger` is by all definitions known to me immutable, but has several non final fields. Final fields are one possibility to guarantee immutability and thread safety but not the only. But then Hibernate will use reflection on final fields just as well (and breaking the Java spec while doing so, but that's another bag of problems)

Comment: Man. You're right :). Anyway, the answer's main claim is still true - the logic should be separated from the entity. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't really care about the object/class. It only knows about the mapping configuration that you set for the object. Hibernate will look for the GET method for the property you specify in your hibernate xml mapping. So you can modify your get method to do as you want and that change won't be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@Transient` Annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property), any property signed transient will not be persisted.
When populating the object from database the transient property will be set using the original value.

Throughout the application use this transient variable, and before persist (you can use @PrePersist annotation), you can populate the value from the transient variable.